# Read text from selected item when there are multiple items in a listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have customized an adapter with a list view with four items in each list item:

```
TextView id = tid
TextView id = tname
TextView id = tgender
TextView id = tage
```

Now on click, I want to get text from the textview of the item with the id 'tid'.

```
public class TeacherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Teacher>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Teacher> teachers;

public TeacherAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Teacher> teachers) {
    super(context, 0, teachers);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.teachers = teachers;
}

public int getCount() {
    return teachers.size();
}

public Teacher getItem(int position) {
    return teachers.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtMobile;
    TextView txtDept;
    TextView txtId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_text_item, null);

        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tName);
        viewHolder.txtMobile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tMobile);
        viewHolder.txtDept = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tDepartment);
        viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tId);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.txtName.setText(teachers.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.txtMobile.setText(teachers.get(position).getMobile());
    viewHolder.txtDept.setText(teachers.get(position).getDepartment());
    viewHolder.txtId.setText(teachers.get(position).getId()+"");

    return convertView;
}
}
```

I have four items in a multiple listview: name, mobileno, department, id. All I want to do is `getId` from the list item when it is clicked.

Comment: can you share your adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code have solved my problem.

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (v != null){
        TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tId);
        Log.e("idthatclicked",textView.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            teacher=  parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
            String text = teacher.getId();
            //TextView tid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tid);
            //String text = tid.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is not a proper way of getting the values for the itemclicked. Think through it and update your answer

Comment: I thought you was right so I updated my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

In onItemClick method of listview, write this code to get the id. here you need to pick up the value from the adapter directly as mentioned below

```
  @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int id= adapter1.getItem(position).getId();
}
```

or

```
    @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

            int id = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).getId();
}
```

Comment: adapter denotes what?

Comment: its an adapter binded to the listview. Are your using a ListActivity or Activity?

Comment: im using ListActivity

Comment: not working with getId() , you can take a look of my answer it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
               ViewHolder holder= (ViewHolder ) view.getTag();                       
               String text = holder.txtId.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

by this way , you can skip the find by resouceId part,use holder instead.

Comment: im using ListActivity , i cant import ViewHolder Class here i guess**

Answer (score -1):

If you have an OnItemClickListener, the view that was clicked is passed to it. Check that the view is not null. Then, do:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View viewThatWasClicked, 
                                     int position, long arg3) {
    TextView tid = (TextView) viewThatWasClicked.findViewById(R.id.tid);

    String text= tid.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: this is not a proper way of getting the values for the itemclicked. Think through it and update your answer